# How to set the variable to 2 decimal places

Tags: jsp, formatting, jstl, variable-assignment

I'm creating a variable in `JSTL` using

```
<c:set var="billableTime" value="${ps.computedAmount}" />
```

My problem is `ps.computedAmount` is not a 2-digit decimal and I want the `ps.computedAmount` to be rounded off to 2-decimals before assigning to `billableTime`. I know how to display a 2-digit number in `JSTL` by using

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${ps.computedAmount}" />
```

But my problem is about assigning a 2-digit value to a `JSTL` variable.

Answer (score 18):

I think you can do it like this:

```
<c:set var="billableTime"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${ps.computedAmount}" /></c:set>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="formattedBillableTime" type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${ps.computedAmount}" />

<c:set var="billableTime" value="${**formattedBillableTime**}" />
```